# accessing anchored tokens from epxress request object

Tags: node.js, express, url, request, anchor

I'm building a Trello bot, for which I need to get the authorization token, the official documentation has listed to frame an auth URL like this:  
`https://trello.com/1/authorize?expiration=1day&name=MyPersonalToken&scope=read&response_type=token&return_url=${MY_RETURN_URL}&key=${API_KEY}` 
    when the user clicks allow, the auth token will be sent as the `GET` method to the `return_url` given in the auth link above. 
   so as expected, I'm getting the correct token but it's not in the form of query or param, the URL looks like `https://return.url.com#32characterslongstring` so how can I parse that token,
I'm using express server, so I tried to get the full URL with `req.url`, `req.originalUrl` or tried logging the `request` object but I'm unable to get that anchored part

I tried testing locally on my machine but still unable to get the token

my only concern is to get the token or full URL
let's say, I'm having a URL like `https://localhost/param#thisiswhatiwanttoget`
so how can I access that part after # on the server-side? or in nodejs / express context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL hash is never sent to the server. You will need to read it on the browser. I am assuming your callback (return) URL is on your server, so you could have some JS code that executes when the page is loaded, reads the hash and then sends it back to the server with an AJAX request.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/hash